# Digitally signing an executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, software-design, software-distribution

I created a python application and converted it to an executable using pyinstaller. How can I digitally sign the executable file. I have looked into Microsoft signtool. However how do I generate or get the digital certificate. The area is a bit hazy to me.

Comment: Digital certificates are signed with other digital certificates. You can sign your own certificates, but that signature is going to be worthless to anyone else. To actually have a certificate of some value, it needs to be signed by a _trusted_ third party (see [wikipedia page about CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)).

Comment: I developed an application using tkinter to automate certain processes. And a company I am currently working as an intern in told me to add those hours on my timesheet. Now as they don't specialized for this sort of work. I need to figure out a way to add a publisher or a certificate to the executable (beta version) so that it is not blocked by any antivirus program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about these things, but I'd say that 1) anti-virus does not care about certificates, it just looks for known virus-like patterns in the exe; 2) having a signed exe may prevent Windows' _"are you sure you want to run this app, it may not be safe blah blah"_ question, but I expect you have to pay to Microsoft if you want them to sign it as safe.

Comment: Right now the issue I have is, if I try running it. It says that the publisher is unknown and there is no option to run it. I need to somehow figure out a way to add the company I work for as the publisher. And later if required they can look into getting authorization for publishing softwares and such. I was given the responsibility to look into it and figure out the necessary steps.

Comment: It is absolutely unclear why you are getting that message. It seems to be a protection software installed by the company itself. You should talk to the company's IT people and ask them what to do.

Comment: I would probably do that as well. However for now I am trying to update the publisher and information of that sort. Can you suggest how to use signtool or any such software to do that.